# Getting a value from textarea that is inside of a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, foreach

So, here is the thing - I have a comment section that is generated withing a `foreach` loop, all the comments have button clicking which will cause bootstrap modal to open with textarea to enter a reply comment.
 The problem is that I can get a value only from first comment on the page, I tried to get value with JS ike this - `var comment = $('#textarea_id').val();` and using only PHP ($_POST) but it works only for the first comment. Also it tried to put unique id for every textarea, unique name and so on but it doesn't help either. 
Here is some code for your visual understanding (Please, notice that I'm using smarty engine but I think it's the same logic as in regular PHP foreach loop, so don't mind it):

```
{foreach from=$comments item=row}
Here is the body of comment and button to trigger reply modal
And this is reply modal with textarea in it:
            <!-- Reply Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="{$row.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
                        <div class="modal-header love-modal">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Reply to <a href="{$abslink}profile/{$row.username}">{$row.username}</a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#" method="post">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="someidfortextarea" name="" rows="8" maxlength="5550"></textarea>
                            </form>
                         </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="reply btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit">Post</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/foreach}
```

So, the main question is - how to get text from textarea which is in `foreach` loop (By php or javascript)?I will be really happy to see any advice or suggestion! Thank you very much!

Comment: can you post you javascript too.

Comment: For now I'm just logging values to browser's console just for debugging purposes, but even if it's about my JS code it's probably has to do with the way I try to get values. `$(function() {
 $(".reply").click(function() {

  var comment = $('#comment').val();
  var topic_id = $('#topic_id').val(); // get the page id from the hidden topic_id field
  var dataFields = {'comment': comment, 'topic_id': topic_id}; // prepare datas string

console.log(comment);
console.log(dataFields);
 });
});
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a shared identifier to relate the button to the matching textarea. `$row.id` seems like a good match.

Disclaimer: untested code, so you might have to finagle it a bit to get it to work properly.

```
{foreach from=$comments item=row}
    ...
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea_{$row.id}" name="" rows="8" maxlength="5550"></textarea>
    ...
    <button id="submit_post_{$row.id}" class="reply btn btn-success" name="submit" type="submit">Post</button>
    ...
{/foreach}
```

Then in your javascript, you can relate it back:

```
$('button.reply').click(function() {
    var button_id = $(this).prop('id');
    var row_id = button_id.replace('submit_post_', '');
    var textarea_id = '#textarea_' + row_id;

    var comment = $(textarea_id).val();

    // now send {comment} to the server using ajax
});
```

I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this, maybe you could use a `data` attribute on the button so you don't have to string-replace bits off the button's `id`. This is just a general idea.

Comment: Hm, to be honest I didn't try to set an unique id for button too, thanks for that hint. I feel we are close but for now I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` I will continue working on it, I'm sure it's almost solved

Comment: Depending on the jQuery version, you might need to use `attr` instead of `prop` to get the id from the button.

Comment: It's jQuery v3.1.1 I will try `attr` now

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: button_id.attr is not a function` - that makes me really upset

Comment: Ah, wait, sorry, I got confused. Yes, prop works fine actually, already checked it the this is in replacing

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I've managed to make it work! Yay!